# What easy zlib tutorials are there?

Tags: c++, c, zlib

I'm looking for a good tutorial on zlib. I'm interested only in decompressing the archives. I also want to know how I can access a desired file inside an archive, preferably by filename alone, if that can be done in zlib at all.

Comment: Preferably, yes, but not necessarily.

Comment: Be aware that zlib is just for (de)compressing a data stream. It's not for dealing with archives or collections of files as zip or tar does, though such other formats might use zlib internally for some of its functioning.

Comment: Look at [libarchive](https://www.libarchive.org) for working with archives of multiple files.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Well there are many zlib articles , tips and tutorials. Some of them are

**1) [Bobobobo's Blog](http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2008/02/23/how-to-use-zlib/)**

This article basically tells you how to use zlib, and there is a snippet of code that will get you going.

> This project shows you how to use zlib. Its
> a console project, because there's no
> need to create a window to demonstrate
> use of zlib.

**2) [zlib: Add Industrial Strength Compression to Your C/C++ Apps](https://www.codeguru.com/cplusplus/zlib-add-industrial-strength-compression-to-your-c-c-apps/)**

> For simplicity's sake, this tutorial
> covers only the basic C-style
> interface. All the concepts inherent
> there will be relevant to most other
> bindings.

Since its in C language, it will be most beneficial to your requirements.

Last, you can use this too available in zlib. From the [manual, Utility Functions](https://zlib.net/manual.html#Utility):

```
ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT uncompress OF((Bytef *dest, uLongf *destLen,
                                   const Bytef *source, uLong sourceLen));
```

Answer (score 8):

See http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html

Answer (score 2):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/zlib.html

Another option worth mentioning here is boost. Note you must compile boost with special flags for zlib support.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to use zlib is in C++ with

https://github.com/rudi-cilibrasi/zlibcomplete

The zlibcomplete library makes it easy because you don't need to do any raw pointer manipulation whatsoever.  It is based on RAII (Resource Allocation is Initialization) which means that all the dynamic allocation and deallocation stuff happens automatically in the constructors.

It is better than the Boost zlib wrapper because it supports flush (necessary for interactive network protocols) and is simpler to use.  The zlibcomplete library uses only regular std::string to send and receive data so no advanced knowledge is required.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to read [`zpipe.c`](https://www.zlib.net/zpipe.c), which has a [walk-through in zlib documentation](https://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html).

It is tiny and comprehensive, implements and illustrates compression and decompression. You can just copy and paste and modify the data stream stuff, for example you may not read and write to files but to memory.

One thing to notice: if you're handling GZIP (instead of deflate), which you may find when making a HTTP request, you need to replace `inflateInit(&strm)` with `inflateInit2(&strm, 16 + MAX_WBITS)`, since GZIP has a bigger header.